# Are After Effects plugins made with the AE sdk cross platform?

Tags: plugins, sdk, cross-platform, after-effects

I am wanting to develop a after effects plugin in c/c++ using the after effects sdk. Are plugins made in this way cross-platform. I will be developing on a Mac, so will the plugin work on windows without any modifications? If not, will I have to make some small adjustments to make it cross platform, or will I have to re-develop the plugin under windows for it to run in windows?

Comment: I've been interested in this for a long time too but I find the After Effects SDK boggling.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your code.

If you use specific platform calls like GET_MAIN_WHND() you would have to alter your code according to each platform.

On the other hand it should be exactly the same code for windows.
just duplicate an existing project, exactly as you did on the mac, and copy your code.

Answer (score 0):

The examples provided with Adobe's SDK are cross-platform. They will build on OSX and Windows (with XCode and Visual Studio) out of the box.

A .plugin bundle will be created for osx and a .aex file will be created for windows.

If you need to rely on libraries, you might have to check if the libraries support Windows and mac.

Here's a good starting point: https://ae-plugins.docsforadobe.dev/
and the SDKs: https://developer.adobe.com/after-effects/